# не запускается бат файл на Windows 10

Tags: bat

Есть следующее задание:

Создать бат скрипт:

- Создающий в текущем каталоге (в котором находится запускаемый
  bat-файл) каталог с названием в виде «Screenshots_текущая_дата» и
  перемещающий туда из текущего каталога все файлы с расширением,
  указанном в качестве первого параметра, передаваемого из командной
  строки.
- Записывающий названия всех перемещенных файлов в файл d:\screenshots.found (дописывает в конец файла или создает новый, если такого не было), который находится в том же каталоге, что и запускаемый bat-файл.
- Архивирующий папку с перемещенными файлами и удаляющий ее оригинал.
- Ожидающий нажатия любой клавиши для своего завершения.

Скрипт выглядит так:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

cd  /d "%-dp0"   ||     exit /b

set "target=Screenshots_%DATE%"

if not exist %target% mkdir %target%
for /f "delims="  %%a in ('2^>nul dir /b /s /a:-1-d *%1^  |  findstr /i /r "\ ....$"') do (
     echo %%a >> d:\screenshots.found
     move "%%-pnxa" %target%

)

cd /d %〜dp0%target%
7z.exe a -t7z archive1.7z *%1

if "!errorlevel!"=="0" (rd /s %target%)

pause
exit
```

Файл не запускается, где здесь ошибка? Подскажите,пожалуйста

Comment: "Файл не запускается" - это не описание проблемы. Описанием может быть
-ничего не происходит (нет видимых изменений)
-выдаются ошибки.

Comment: Первое, с чего стоит начать  - запуск этого батника из командной строки, а не мышекликом.

Comment: Вполне себе он запускается.

Comment: При проблемах с пакетным файлом первое, что положено сделать - закомментировать `@echo off` и внимательно изучить сообщения в окне консоли.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> cd  /d "%-dp0"   ||     exit /b
> ```

Тильда должна быть, а не минус.

> ```
> cd /d %〜dp0%target%
> ```

И тут тоже какая-то юникодщина вместо тильды.